# Understanding Java recursion using Eclipse's debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, recursion

I am going through some simple recursion exercises in Java in order to understand the concept (which I struggle with). For all my study up to this point, I have relied heavily on Eclipse's debugger in order to understand exactly what my code is doing. However, when it comes to recursion, I find this not to be the case, because it is difficult to track exactly what is happening.

Considering the following code, a method that returns the `n`th Fibonacci number:

```
public int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

When using the debugger for this code, it's pretty difficult to track exactly what is happening and where/when. With only one variable, it changes every step, and, with a small `n` value, such as 7, it is already becoming difficult to track, due to the fact that there are so many steps that are executed before 13 is eventually reached.

I would like to know:

1. How can I debug my recursion code (in general) in a better way, in order to better understand recursion?
2. Am I focussing too much on debugging for this sort of thing, considering the concept `return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)` is simple to understand?

Comment: Have you tried to draw the call structure on a sheet of paper? This might be a good exercise to understand what the recursion is doing.

Comment: A simple output (sysout or logs) of Input/Ouput of the recursive method helps understanding IMHO

Comment: @RC: please don't teach him to do debugging by printing to system output. I know too many developers doing exactly that and this often makes it into production code.

Comment: ++ for trying to understand not only recursion but also the debugger.

Comment: You may want to look carefully at the call stack.Eclipse allows you to select a stack frame and see the values of variables in that stack frame. This can be useful in understanding recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug it using a simple `System.out.prinln()` in each instruction where you print `n` value and its `fibonnacci` value.

Here's an example code:

```
public int fibonacci(int n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
     System.out.println("your value is: " +n+ " and its Fibonacci value is: "+n);
     return n;
  } else {
    System.out.println("your value is: " +n+ " and its Fibonacci value is: "+fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
}
```

You can test the **[DEMO here](https://ideone.com/FDHR1T)**.

Answer (score 5):

### How can I debug my recursion code?

First, make sure you have switched to the Debug perspective and you're seeing the correct windows (`Variables`, `Expressions`, `Debug` and your source code) e.g. like this:

[image: Eclipse - debug recursion]

Next, note that in `Debug` you can see how often the method is currently called. This list will grow and shrink depending on how many methods were called and have not returned yet.

You can click on one of the methods to change the scope. See how the contents of `Variables` changes when you change the scope.

Finally, to check arbitrary things, enter expressions in the `Expressions` window. This is almost like live coding. You can inspect virtually anything.

### Am I focussing too much on debugging?

No. Learn doing it right and it will save you much time later.

Adding a `System.out.println()` needs to recompile and you need to reproduce the situation which is not always that simple.

Answer (score 1):

"Inline" code makes it more difficult to use the Eclipse debugger because it has a strong focus on showing local variables which are not present. You can make this easier to step through by making things more verbose and saving to variables. This way you can more easily see what is happening and what results are. For example, modifying your code as follows will make it easier to use the debugger on:

```
public int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        int nMinus1 = fibonacci(n - 1);
        int nMinus2 = fibonacci(n - 2);
        int retValue = nMinus1 + nMinus2;
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not attempted to compile this code.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to grasp recursion and, for one reason or another, I never found the debuggers useful. I'll try to explain you how I do and it doesn't involve the debugger (**disclaimer**: this is a personal method and it might by incorrect or not general).

1. In recursive code you always have at least a termination block and a
   recursion block. Isolate mentally these 2 sections.

   `return n;` -> termination block

   `return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);` -> recursion block
2. The recursion block express the abstract rule(s) of recursion. Instead of having those values in variables `Fn1` and `Fn2`, you obtain these values using the same function. Think about a brick wall: your recursive function creates the wall adding a brick to an existing wall. Inside the recursion block, at a certain step, you don't mind who and how the existing wall has been created, you simply add to it a new brick. It happens then that the wall has been created by the same function, one brick at the time.
3. At the termination block the code is called with some values. What should happen at the end of the process to that value? Speaking about Fibonacci, at the end of the process (`n = 1` or `n = 0`) I have to again add these number to the total. This is done by the recursive block. In other words the termination block gives the concrete values (and not a process on how to obtain them) to the recursion block.

When I have to troubleshoot I print the values at every step, and this is the best solution I've found for me. Then I check that they are what they are supposed to be. For your Fibonacci, I would like to see an output like

Code:

```
public static int fibonacci( int n ) {
    System.out.println( "\nInput value: " + n );
    if( n == 0 || n == 1 ) {
        System.out.println( "Terminating block value: " + n );
        return n;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println( "Recursion block value: fibonacci(" + (n - 1) + ") + fibonacci(" + (n - 2) + ")" );
        int result = fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 );
        System.out.println( "Recursion block return value: " + result );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input value: 4
Recursion block value: fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)

Input value: 3
Recursion block value: fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)

Input value: 2
Recursion block value: fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)

Input value: 1
Terminating block value: 1

Input value: 0
Terminating block value: 0
Recursion block return value: 1

Input value: 1
Terminating block value: 1
Recursion block return value: 2

Input value: 2
Recursion block value: fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)

Input value: 1
Terminating block value: 1

Input value: 0
Terminating block value: 0
Recursion block return value: 1
Recursion block return value: 3
```

You can also find useful to read about [Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), which is strictly related to recursion.